# get sum and difference of fields from two tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables

1. sales:

| sale_date | total_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-24 | 59000 |
| 2021-03-24 | 25000 |
| 2021-03-25 | 88000 |
| 2021-03-25 | 10000 |
| 2021-03-26 | 67000 |
| 2021-03-27 | 99000 |

2. credit_sales:

| credit_sale_date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-24 | 10000 |
| 2021-03-24 | 2000 |
| 2021-03-24 | 3000 |
| 2021-03-25 | 1000 |
| 2021-03-25 | 5000 |
| 2021-03-25 | 6000 |
| 2021-03-26 | 22000 |
| 2021-03-27 | 15000 |

Expected Result:

| date | total_amount | cash_amount | credit_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-24 |  |  |  |
| 2021-03-25 |  |  |  |
| 2021-03-26 |  |  |  |
| 2021-03-27 |  |  |  |

total_amount is the sum of 'total_amount' from sales table of a particular date

credit_amount = sum of 'amount' from credit_sales table of the particular date

cash_amount = sum of 'total_amount' from sales table - sum of 'amount' from credit_sales table of the particular date

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union and group

```
select sale_date, sum(total_amount) as total_amount,
   sum(credit_amount) as credit_amount,
   sum(total_amount) - sum(credit_amount) as cash_amount
from (
    select sale_date, total_amount, 0 as credit_amount
    from sales 
    union all
    select credit_sale_date, 0 as total_amount, amount as credit_amount
    from credit_sales
) t
group by sale_date
```

Comment: Dear Sir, this query throws the following error:  

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sale_date' in 'field list' (SQL: select sale_date, sum(total_amount) as total_amount, sum(credit_amount) as credit_amount, sum(total_amount) - sum(credit_amount) as cash_amount from ( select sale_date, total_amount, 0 as credit_amount from sales union all select sale_date, 0 as total_amount, credit_amount from credit_sales ) t )  

I tried to change the sale_date to credit_sale_date in the last select query but it throws: Unknown column 'credit_amount' in 'field list' error.

Comment: Corrected names

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 't.sale_date'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select sale_date, sum(total_amount) as total_amount, sum(credit_amount) as credit_amount, sum(total_amount) - sum(credit_amount) as cash_amount from ( select sale_date, total_amount, 0 as credit_amount from sales union all select credit_sale_date, 0 as total_amount, amount as credit_amount from credit_sales ) t )

Comment: Ops, group by is missing, added

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.

Comment: Sir what is the query to get this data for every month and year

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please ask a separate question and explain it.

Comment: Sir, I need the same sql as you have provided above, but now for monthly and yearly report. Two separate sql: one for monthly, one for yearly. I hope i explained it correctly.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    sale_date as date, sum(DISTINCT total_amount) as total_amount, sum(DISTINCT amount) as credit_amount, sum(DISTINCT total_amount) + sum(DISTINCT amount) as cash_amount
from
    sales, credit_sales
where 
    sales.sale_date = credit_sales.credit_sale_date
GROUP BY sales.sale_date
```

Comment: Dear sir, this  query is working but when the value in "amount" or "credit_amount" field is same for the same date twice, then the output is not as expected. I tried to run the sql without the DISTINCT keyword but could not get the right output. Thank you.